# How to save the videos in Partcular folder in iPhone Gallery in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, alassetslibrary

I  have more than 10 videos url in one view which is coming from Web service. I am showing these videos thumbnails in `UITableview`.
I  am Using following code where I m Saving These Videos  to gallery in particular folder

This is my code::

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:Urlstr];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

// Write it to cache directory
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mov"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
// After that use this path to save it to PhotoLibrary
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:@"MyFolderName" resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group)
 {
     //How to get the album URL?
     // saving the video in  gallery though file path and document directory
     [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
         }else {
             NSLog(@"Done :)");
         }
     }];
 }
    failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                            //Handle the error
                        }];
```

Now the issues is it is not saving my video to My folder. But it creates the folder and saving the video  in default video folder of gallery.

Anyone please suggest me  why it going like this.

Comment: Why don't you use or get a hint from https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum

Comment: hii poles.. i have implemented this. but this gives many errors.

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)createAlbumInPhotosLibrary:(NSString *)photoAlbumName videoAtFile:(NSURL *)videoURL {

     // RELIVIT_moments
     __block PHFetchResult *photosAsset;
     __block PHAssetCollection *collection;
     __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder;

      // Find the album
      PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
      fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", photoAlbumName];
      collection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum
                                                              subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny
                                                              options:fetchOptions].firstObject;
      // Create the album
      if (!collection)
      {
          [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
          PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *createAlbum = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle:photoAlbumName];
          placeholder = [createAlbum placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection];

       } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

              if (success)
              {
                 PHFetchResult *collectionFetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[placeholder.localIdentifier]
                                                                                                                options:nil];
                 collection = collectionFetchResult.firstObject;

                 [self saveVideoInRelivitFolderSetPlaceHolder:placeholder photosAsset:photosAsset collection:collection VideoAtFile:videoURL];

                }

            }];

        } else {

            [self saveVideoInRelivitFolderSetPlaceHolder:placeholder photosAsset:photosAsset collection:collection VideoAtFile:videoURL];
        }

 }

 - (void)saveVideoInRelivitFolderSetPlaceHolder:(PHObjectPlaceholder *)placeholderLocal photosAsset:(PHFetchResult *)photosAssetLocal  collection:(PHAssetCollection *)collectionLocal VideoAtFile:(NSURL *)videoURL {

        __block PHFetchResult *photosAsset = photosAssetLocal;
        __block PHAssetCollection *collection = collectionLocal;
        __block PHObjectPlaceholder *placeholder = placeholderLocal;

        // Save to the album
        [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
            PHAssetChangeRequest *assetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:videoURL];
            placeholder = [assetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];
            photosAsset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];

            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection
                                                                                                                          assets:photosAsset];
            [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[placeholder]];

        } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            if (success)
            {
                NSLog(@"done");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }];

 }
```

Comment: similar or easier question with a Large Bounty .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791151/100-bounty-actually-get-the-filename-of-image-saved-to-photos-album-2017-ios10